# Reactive variables are not working - svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

Reactive variables are not working in my svelte application. When I log them on my console they are `undefined`.

I have in `App.svelte` the following relevant code

```
<script>
 let polls = [
  {
    question: "JavaScript or Python?",
    answerA: "JavaScript",
    answerB: "Python",
    votesA: 16,
    votesB: 4
  }
 ]

 const handleVote = e => {/* increase vote A or vote B by 1*/}
</script>

<PollsList {polls} on:vote={handleVote}/>
```

In `PollsList.svelte` I have the following relevant code

```
<script>
  export let polls = [];
</script>

{#each polls as poll (poll.id)}
  <PollItem {poll} on:vote/>
{/each}
```

and in my `PollItem.svelte` I have the following relevant code

```
<script>
 import {createEventDispatcher} from "svelte";

 const disptach = createEventDispatcher();
 export let poll;
 
 $: totalVotes = poll.votesA + poll.votesB;
 $: percentA = Math.round(poll.votesA / totalVotes) * 100;
 $: percentB = Math.round(poll.votesB / totalVotes) * 100;

 console.log(totalVotes, percentA, percentB, poll.votesA, poll.votesB);

const handleVote = (option, id) => dispatch("vote", {option, id});
</script>

<div>
 <div class = "answer" on:click={() => handleVote("a", poll.id)}{poll.answerA}</div>
 <div class = "answer" on:click={() => handleVote("b", poll.id)}{poll.answerB}</div>
</div>
```

The `console.log` in the last code gives `undefined, undefined, undefined, 16, 4`, which means although `poll.votesA` and `poll.votesB` reach the component, the reactive variables are `undefined`. Why is that? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case the variables are not done evaluated yet to log them and the way to fix that is be usning console.log reactively like the following:

```
$: totalVotes = poll.votesA + poll.votesB;
$: percentA = Math.round(poll.votesA / totalVotes) * 100;
$: percentB = Math.round(poll.votesB / totalVotes) * 100;

$: console.log(totalVotes, percentA, percentB, poll.votesA, poll.votesB);
```

or make it all inside a block:

```
let totalVotes, percentA, percentB;
$:{
    totalVotes = poll.votesA + poll.votesB;
    percentA = Math.round(poll.votesA / totalVotes) * 100;
    percentB = Math.round(poll.votesB / totalVotes) * 100;
    console.log(totalVotes, percentA, percentB, poll.votesA, poll.votesB);
}
```